# how to append the data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to add the value into the span using dom. But now i am using string manipulation. how to change this into the dom or append the value . i need to get the return value in html formate using dom.

Comment: Can you provide with more details About what you need to do ?

Comment: i need to add the below to statements(span) in to the html page using the dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define layer.id as some text and this will get replace in all span element content

```
$.each($("span"),function(){
$(this).html(layer.id);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can append like following :

```
$('.ClassName').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').after('<p>Test</p>');
$('#id').before('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$("<li class='" + liClass + "'>" + preElement + 
  "<label for='" + layer.id + "'>" + layer.name + "</label>").appendTo('ul.class'); 
                                                               //----------^^^^^ 
                                                               // use the id 
                                                               // or class of 
                                                               //the specific ul
```

use `appendTo()` instead return and append it to your element.

`(as i see you are returning li then append it to the ul)`

Comment: i need to fully change this dom type using setelements, setattributes etc.,

Comment: _setelements, setattributes etc_ don't get it.

Comment: my code is working successfully but. i need to remove the span and other sting manipulation and using the dom i manipulate the valuues