# How to display the value in html page using dom jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to display the value in html page using dom jQuery, but its does not display the value. My code:

```
$(document.createElement("li"))
    .append(
        $(document.createElement("span"))
        .attr({
            id: id,
            name: name,
            value: name
        })
    )
    .addClass('firstli')
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` element doesn't have `value` property, you should use `text` instead.

```
var $li = $('<li/>');
$('<span/>', {
    id: layer.id,
    name: layer.name,
    text: layer.name,
    'class': 'bullet'
}).appendTo($li)
```

Comment: thank you. but i am using same idea here but it is does not display the html name

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("<li></li>").append(
    $("<span></span>").attr({
        id: layer.id,
        name: layer.name,
    }).text(layer.name)
).addClass('bullet').appendTo(document);
```

And may be you want to append it to document

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819157/how-to-append-the-data-using-jquery verify this link. this is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

With your above code you just have created the elements, you still need to **add them** to the DOM, you have [**several methods**](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) for that, for example you could use `.appendTo()` to append your elements at the end of some other existent element in the DOM, so your following line:

```
).addClass('bullet')
```

would be changed for this one:

```
).addClass('bullet').appendTo('#someDOMelement');
```